# Delete Query MySQL : Column Count Doesn't Match Value Count at Row 1

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete all rows from a table with a particular id.
my query is:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE x_id='46';
```

the error returned is:

> **#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

my table has a composite primary key `x_id` is one of the columns in the primary key.

Please Help!

Comment: Do you have a trigger on delete that might be failing?

Comment: `DELETE * FROM table_name WHERE x_id='46';`

Comment: In a test on the mysql instance on my computer, I am able to delete using one field in a composite primary key.  How is the key created and is there a constraint of some sort?

Comment: Check your trigger. Perhaps you updated the table but forgot to update the trigger

Answer (score 5):

That error is strange for a delete statement. It is most likely coming from badly written trigger that is being executed as a result of the delete.

This error would most likely be encountered on an insert statement such as the following:

```
insert into foo(bar, baz)
select bar, baz, foobar, 2
from myTable
```

Note how the insert statement specifies 2 columns, but provides 4 values.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to provide a second value to the delete query to match the composite index for the row.

DELETE FROM CPI 
 WHERE (CountryID, Year) IN (('AD', 2010), ('AF', 2009), ('AG', 1992))

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** 
You may have a trigger on this table, then you changed the table structure.
Now, you may get this error when you delete, insert, or update in this table (depending on the trigger event you specified).

**Solution:**
To solve this issue, you have to update the trigger as well, the number of columns of the trigger should match the number of the columns of the table.