# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 while Deleting a record

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table called `XXX` when I'm trying to delete a record the from table I am getting a column count that doesn't match the value count at row 1.

This is my table structure

```
  ╔═════════════╦════════════╦══════════╦═════╦════════════════╗
  ║    Field    ║    Type    ║   Null   ║ Key ║     Extra      ║  
  ╠═════════════╬════════════╬══════════╬═════╬════════════════╣
  ║ id          ║ bigint(20) ║ NO       ║ PK  ║ auto_increment ║
  ║ building_id ║ bigint(20) ║ unsigned ║ YES ║ FK             ║ 
  ╚═════════════╩════════════╩══════════╩═════╩════════════════╝
```

sample data set

table name : building

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  2 | B    |
|  3 | C    |
+----+------+
```

table name : mapping

```
+----+-------------+
| id | building_id |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |
|  2 |           1 |
|  3 |           2 |
|  4 |           5 |
+----+-------------+
```

I'm trying to execute the following query

```
DELETE
FROM mapping
WHERE building_id = 1;
```

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: It might be a trigger: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667504/delete-query-mysql-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1 ... normally this error message would not be expected from a delete.

Comment: Then reword your question to focus on the trigger problem.

Comment: yes its because of one trigger which has miss match column count. Thank you so much.